# How to remove citation parts that miss parentheses

Tags: r, regex

**DATA**

```
mystring1 <- "Other work has shown that, in addition to language-general features such as a decreased speaking rate and an expanded pitch range, clear speech production involves the enhancement of the acoustic-phonetic distance between phonologically contrastive categories e.g., Ferguson and Kewley-Port, 2002; Krause and Braida, 2004, Picheny et al, 1986; Smiljanic and Bradlow, 2005, 2007."

mystring2 <- "Other work has shown that, in addition to language-general features such as a decreased speaking rate and an expanded pitch range, clear speech production involves the enhancement of the acoustic-phonetic distance between phonologically contrastive categories e.g., Ferguson and Kewley-Port, 2002; Krause and Braida, 2004, Picheny et al, 1986; Smiljanic and Bradlow, 2005, 2007. Therefore, reduced sensitivity to any or all of the language-specific acoustic-phonetic dimensions of contrast and clear speech enhancement would yield a diminished clear speech benefit for non-native listeners. This may appear somewhat surprising given that clear speech production was elicited in our studies by instructing the talkers to speak clearly for the sake of listeners with either a hearing impairment or from a different native language background. However, as discussed further in Bradlow and Bent 2002, the limits of clear speech as a means of enhancing non-native speech perception likely reflect the “mistuning” that characterizes spoken language communication between native and non-native speakers."
```

I'd like to receive some help for regular expression. I got some text data. Basically I want to remove citation parts that appear between last word in a sentence and a period. However, parentheses are somehow missing. `mystring1` is an example for that. In this example, I want to remove `e.g., Ferguson and Kewley-Port, 2002; Krause and Braida, 2004, Picheny et al, 1986; Smiljanic and Bradlow, 2005, 2007`. But this sentence is just one of the sentences in a paragraph. `mystring2` contains three more sentences following `mystring1`. My goal is to remove the citation part from `mystring2`. But I have not been successful; the pattern is removing more texts than I want. How can I revise regex pattern? Thank you for your help in advance.

```
# This works for mystring1.
gsub(x = mystring1, pattern = "e\\.g\\.,.*[0-9]{4}(?=.)", replacement = "", perl = T)

[1] "Other work has shown that, in addition to language-general features such as a 
     decreased speaking rate and an expanded pitch range, clear speech production involves
     the enhancement of the acoustic-phonetic distance between phonologically contrastive
     categories ."

# But this pattern does not work for mystring2; gsub() removes texts more than I want.
gsub(x = mystring2, pattern = "e\\.g\\.,.*[0-9]{4}(?=.)", replacement = "", perl = T)

[1] "Other work has shown that, in addition to language-general features such as a decreased
     speaking rate and an expanded pitch range, clear speech production involves the
     enhancement of the acoustic-phonetic distance between phonologically contrastive
     categories , the limits of clear speech ... (I trimmed texts here) speakers."
```

Comment: Given the very large amount of text, I'd say that this isn't a minimal question.  Can you phrase your regex problem with just say 2-3 sentences?  And include the R code you have already tried.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If I rephrase my question, I'd say "Why does the regular expression pattern in my `gsub()` works for `mystring1`, but not `mystring2`? Does this help you?

Comment: Note `(?=.)` matches a location that is followed with any char  but  a line break char (with PCRE regex engine behavior you set with `perl=T`). `.` does not match across lines in PCRE regex, in TRE, it does.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried `gsub(x = mystring2, pattern = "e\\.g\\.,.*[0-9]{4}(?=\\.)", replacement = "", perl = T)`. But this did not generate the expected result. I also tried `gsub(x = mystring2, pattern = "e\\.g\\.,.*[0-9]{4}(?=(\\.))", replacement = "", perl = T)`, but this did not generate the result either.

Comment: Ok, but the thing is the same string is removed in both strings. I do not understand what pattern you need to remove. Also, there are some strange chars between the four digits and `.`, some `` chars. Try `gsub(x = mystring2, pattern = "(?s)\\be\\.g\\.,.*?[0-9]{4}[^\\w.]*(?=\\.)", replacement = "", perl = T)`. See the [**R demo**](https://ideone.com/uWb9vM).

Comment: Looks like a problem with the default greedy pattern, eating all from first delimiter up to last one. Some contrast might help, such as: `e\.g\.[^]*(?=)` (dunno if that `` has to be replaced).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think the strange spaces exist because I wanted to display all texts in this question. Otherwise the strings are too long to fit in the window. If necessary, I change that part so that SO users can avoid any further confusion.

Comment: Ok, does https://ideone.com/s0xM2C work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżewYes, the link is providing the expected results. Could you provide the code with explanation as your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
\be\.g\.,.*?[0-9]{4}[^\w.]*(?=\.)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kuDTyk/2/).

**Details**

- `\be\.g\.` - a whole word `e.g.` (`\b` is a word boundary)
- `,` -  a comma
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars (add `(?s)` at the pattern start to make it match line breaks, too)
- `[0-9]{4}` - four digits
- `[^\w.]*` - 0+ chars other than word chars and dot
- `(?=\.)` - (a positive lookahead matching a location where) a `.` must be immediately to the right of the current location.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/s0xM2C):

```
rx <- "\\be\\.g\\.,.*?[0-9]{4}[^\\w.]*(?=\\.)"
gsub(x = mystring1, pattern = rx, replacement = "", perl = TRUE)
## => [1] "Other work has shown that, in addition to language-general features such as a decreased speaking rate and an expanded pitch range, clear speech production involves the enhancement of the acoustic-phonetic distance between phonologically contrastive categories ."
gsub(x = mystring2, pattern = rx, replacement = "", perl = TRUE)
## => [1] "Other work has shown that, in addition to language-general features such as a decreased speaking rate and an expanded pitch range, clear speech production involves the enhancement of the acoustic-phonetic distance between phonologically contrastive categories . Therefore, reduced sensitivity to any or all of the language-specific acoustic-phonetic dimensions of contrast and clear speech enhancement would yield a diminished clear speech benefit for non-native listeners. This may appear somewhat surprising given that clear speech production was elicited in our studies by instructing the talkers to speak clearly for the sake of listeners with either a hearing impairment or from a different native language background. However, as discussed further in Bradlow and Bent 2002, the limits of clear speech as a means of enhancing non-native speech perception likely reflect the “mistuning” that characterizes spoken language communication between native and non-native speakers."
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. :)